# Why is $\langle \partial_{\mu} f(x) \rangle=0$?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

I'm reading page 488 of [Hobson, Efstathiou & Lasenby](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~fvon4093/introgr.pdf), and I don't understand something they write... so I came here.

The concept they describe is in linearised general relativity. In particular, they are describing the averaging process over small spacetime regions that makes it possible to define the energy-momentum tensor of gravitatonal waves.

They say that since we are averaging of all directions at each point, first derivatives average to zero. That is, for any function of position $f(x)$, we have $\langle \partial_{\mu} f(x) \rangle=0$. Here $x = (x^1,x^2,x^3)$, which is an index-notation version of the 'standard' $(x,y,z)$.

---

**Edit**

By 'average', I assume they mean an integral. So, if we take the simplest possible case for starters, we would have a 1D spacetime, say the $x$ lined. So, all functions of position, are just $f(x)$.

So, I would interpret
\begin{equation}
\langle f(x) \rangle = \int f(x) dx.
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle \partial_{x} f(x) \rangle &= \partial_{x} \int f(x) dx \\
&=f(x).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So, how can this be zero?

Comment: Please do not migrate this to Maths.SE

Comment: Isn't this just another way of saying that we're in a flat background (considering the fact that it's linearized gravity you mentioned)? But I'm not sure to be honest :) Cheers,
a friendly helper

Comment: I don't own the books so I can't really determine the context. Could it have to do with the fact that the average amplitude of a sinusoidal wave is zero?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. If you click the link in my question, it takes you to Google, which provides a copy of the book in PDF.

Comment: In the book they consider small spacetime regions, which we can consider flat. And $\partial_{\mu}a(x)$ is just the gradient of that function. Having a flat space and averaging over all direction gives you zero.

Comment: What Nijankowski V. said. Basically for every direction where $f$ increases there is a corresponding direction where it decreases (the opposite direction). In flat space there is no chance of subtleties from the measure, so averaging over all directions gives zero.

Comment: But why is it that "for every direction where $f$ increases there is a corresponding direction where it decreases"? This is not obvious to me. What do you mean by " there is no chance of subtleties from the measure"? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user16307 If $f$ increases in the direction $\hat{x}$ then it decreases in the direction $-\hat{x}$, as long as it is differentiable. Since the space is flat the $-\hat{x}$ direction counts as much as the $\hat{x}$ direction in the integral.

Comment: @MichaelBrown I don't understand. Taking the case of a 1D spacetime. If $f(x) = x^{2}$ and we choose to position ourselves and $x=0$, we see that $f$ increases if we look in the $+x$ direction but it also increases if we look in the $-x$ direction.

Comment: Response to flags: I do not see the artifacts that you are talking about: all the comments look good and all the math blocks appear to be closed. It is possible that you have a corrupted version of MathJax cached, please try forcibly reloading the page and/or clearing your caches. If the problem persists, open an issue on meta and include your OS/browser data and a screenshot.

Comment: @dmckee I also flagged the issue under 'flat this question' (at the top of the page) at the same time I flagged the actual comment, and it was removed shortly after.

Comment: Yes. I cleared the comment flag thinking that another moderator had fixed the situation and forgotten to clear it---because I don't see a problem on my machine. It was only when you flagged again that I realized that we are seeing different things. Usually that is a sign of bad javascript in your cache. If it is not we should have a meta post about it.

Comment: @user16307 Okay, true. But we're talking about first order changes here. I should have clarified. In your example $\partial_x x^2 = 2 x = 0$ at $x=0$, there is no first order change.

Answer (score 2):

We agree with OP that Ref. 1 does not explain the averaging procedure $\langle \cdots \rangle$ adequately. For reference, the relevant section of Ref. 1 reads:

> *One way of circumventing this problem is to take seriously the fact that the energy–momentum of a gravitational field at a point in spacetime has no real meaning in general relativity, since at any particular event one can always transform to a free-falling frame in which gravitational effects disappear. This suggests that, at each point in spacetime, one should average $G^{(2)}_{\mu\nu}$ over a small region in order to probe the physical curvature
>   of the spacetime, which gives a gauge-invariant measure of the gravitational
>   field strength. Denoting this averaging process by $\langle \cdots \rangle$, one should thus replace (17.55) by*
>
> $$\tag{17.57} t_{\mu\nu}~\equiv~\frac{c^4}{8\pi G} \langle G^{(2)}_{\mu\nu}\rangle.$$
>
> *Having made this identification, our task is now an algebraic one of determining the form of $\langle G^{(2)}_{\mu\nu}\rangle$ as a function of $h_{\mu\nu}$. This is rather a cumbersome calculation, but the job is made somewhat easier by averaging over small spacetime regions. Since we are averaging over all directions at each point, first derivatives average to zero. Thus, for any function of position $a(x)$, we have $\langle \partial_{\mu}a(x)\rangle$.*

Here the superscript $(2)$ refers to terms that are second-order in $h_{\mu\nu}$.

The averaging procedure is explained in greater detail in Ref. 2 as part of the *shortwave approximation/formalism* in the limit of small typical wave amplitude $A\ll 1$ and typical wavelength $\lambda \ll R$ much smaller than the typical radius $R$ of curvature.

This is essentially a Wilsonian effective theory, where one integrates out UV modes to be left with IR modes. However, one should keep in mind that Ref. 2 are considering the UV modes as *classical* configurations (as opposed to *quantum* fluctuations), so rather than *integrating out* in path integral sense, Ref. 2 is  *averaging out.*

Technically, the averaging procedure $\langle \ldots \rangle$ in Ref. 2. is called the *Brill-Hartle average.*

To convey the main idea in an oversimplified manner, the average procedure $\langle \ldots \rangle$ is taken over several wavelengths of a plane gravitational wave of the form

$$\tag{1} a(x)~=~f\left(c(x)+A\sin(k\cdot x)\right),$$

where the IR part $c(x)$ depends so slowly on position $x$, that it can be treated as a constant in the average procedure, and the derivative $\partial_{\mu}c(x)$ is negligible. So we are essentially just averaging the first derivative

$$\tag{2} \partial_{\mu}a(x)~=~f^{\prime}\left(c(x)+A\sin(k\cdot x)\right)~\partial_{\mu}\left(c(x)+A\sin(k\cdot x)\right)~\approx~f^{\prime}\left(c(x)+A\sin(k\cdot x)\right)~k_{\mu}A\cos(k\cdot x)$$

over several wavelengths and getting zero. The detailed form $(1)$ of $a(x)$ does not matter as long as it is approximately periodic.

References:

1. M.P. Hobson, G.P. Efstathiou, and  A.N. Lasenby, *General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists,* 2005, p. 488.
2. C.W. Misner, K.S. Thorne, and J.A. Wheeler, *[Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_%28book%29),* 1973, Section 35.13-35.15, p. 964-973.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused by the language "averaging over all directions at each point," which doesn't seem to be what they are actually doing. This is averaging an approximately periodic function over positions, not arbitrary functions over directions. \*head scratch\* I'm happy to have my answer removed or un-accepted (is that possible?) if it's irrelevant.

Comment: Very cool, I particularly like the slowly changing constant!

Comment: @Qmechanic So, are you saying that the average is zero because $a$ is periodic? Also, what physical entity is represented by the $c$ that you use? I've not seen a wave with this form before. On p.969 of MTW, they say that the error incured from the averaging gradients to zero is $O(\lambda/R)$, where R is the length-scale over which the background metric tensor changes. I was wondering where this error would come from, specifically if it was from $a$. Finally, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function $f$ in the direction $\vec{n}$ is defined as

$$ \nabla_{\vec{n}}f \equiv \vec{n}\cdot\nabla f $$

where $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector. Integrating this over $\vec{n}$ gives

$$ \left< \nabla f \right> \equiv \int \mathrm{d}\vec{n}\ \nabla_{\vec{n}}f = \int \mathrm{d}\vec{n}\ \vec{n}\cdot\nabla f = \nabla f \cdot \int \mathrm{d}\vec{n}\ \vec{n} = 0 $$

If you need to see a particular example pick some ridiculous function like this one I just made up (in two dimensions, just cause):

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{\cos(x y)}{2 y^2} - x \sin(x^2 + y^2) $$

and take the average of the gradient at the point $(x,y)=(3,2)$, pictured as the red dot below.

[image: a ridiculous function]

Mathematica tells me that the gradient of this function evaluated at the point of interest is, in (x,y) components,

$$(-(\sin(6)/4)-\sin(13)-18 \cos(13),\ -((3 \sin(6))/8)-\cos(6)/8-12 \cos(13))$$

So in general the derivative of $f$ in the direction of the unit vector $\vec{n} = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$ is

$$ \vec{n}\cdot(-(\sin(6)/4)-\sin(13)-18 \cos(13),\ -((3 \sin(6))/8)-\cos(6)/8-12 \cos(13))$$

which works out to some stupid sinusoidal function of $\theta$.

Now it should be easy to convince yourself that the average over directions is

$$ \int \mathrm{d}\theta\ (\cdots) = 0 $$

It should be obvious that the choice of function is completely arbitrary, so long as it is differentiable at the point of interest.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense. I think my problem was that, to me, the result seems counter-intuitive. Nice graph btw :). Also, if you didn't see, I have edited the link in my question.

Comment: @user16307 The link goes to an error page for me... I think I might have the book anyway, I just need to dig it out. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Weird. If I use Chrome, the link (http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~fvon4093/introgr.pdf) works, but with IE it doesn't. Maybe my browser has cached it and it's now been removed.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Nice Polynomials!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot find this book, but it is most probably a standard symmetry argument -- a nonzero average would mean a preferred space-time direction.

More formally. Let us introduce two variables:
$$x_\rho \quad \mbox{and} \quad x'_\sigma=\Lambda^\rho_\sigma x_\rho$$
With arbitrary Loretnz transformation $\Lambda$.

I'm pretty sure that the average you are talking about shouldn't care about what variable are we using to average over:
$$\langle f(x_\rho)\rangle=\langle f(x'_\sigma)\rangle$$
Let us differentiate both sides with $\partial_\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}$
$$\langle \partial_\mu f(x_\rho)\rangle=\langle \partial_\mu f(\Lambda^\rho_\sigma x_\rho)\rangle$$
$$\langle \partial_\mu f(x_\rho)\rangle=\langle \Lambda^\sigma_\mu \partial_\sigma f( x_\rho)\rangle$$

Using linearity and denoting $\langle \partial_\mu f(x)\rangle = A_\mu$:

$$A_\mu=\Lambda^\sigma_\mu A_\sigma$$
For arbitrary $\Lambda$ that could be satisfied only if $A_\mu=0$.

Comment: I follow this all the way down to the last line, where I don't understand why you say that $A_{\mu}$ must be zero. P.s. I have edited the link so you will definitely be able to access the book.

Comment: @user16307 umm.. it is quite strange that *this* step is difficult for you... Ok, can you provide a nonzero 3D vector which stays the same for arbitrary 3D rotations?

Comment: Of course not. But to me, it looks like you start of with some equation in $x$ and then re-write this equation in $A$, and nothing more. I can't see why you need $A_{\mu}=0$ from this, anymore than you would need $x^{\prime}_{\sigma}=0$ in your first equation.

Comment: @user16307 Have you seen, say, how the Euler-Lagrange equation are derived?

Comment: I have seen a derivation, yes.

Comment: Are you thinking of Gauss' theorem? Because, I had the idea of going down that route. Consider a spacetime volume of $dV$ large enough to contain many oscillations but still smaller than the background curvature (yes, I'm working on a more general case than Hobson). In this case, $\int\int\int \nabla \boldsymbol{f}\cdot dV = \int\int \boldsymbol{f}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} dS$. If we assume that most of the energy of the GW is contained in our volume, then $\boldsymbol{f}$ vanished at the boundary. So, RHS=0, so LHS=0, and we used arbitrary dV, so $\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{f}=0$